# Wordpress Redirection URL with query string not redirecting

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using the Wordpress Redirection plugin to redirect from the homepage to another page on the site.

`/` redirects to `example.com/project-management-online-short-course/`

However, when I type a URL like `example.com/?s=randomstring` it doesn't redirect.

I have tried several regex string none seem to work. Is it possible to catch these query strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can Checkout with this query hope this help for you.

```
      <?php /*  
       Template Name: Your Custom page redirect
           */ 

      header('Location: http://example.com/project-management-online-short-course/');
      exit();

       ?>
```

if this is not working you can checkout with this link:-
 https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in you functions.php of active theme.

```
function check_user_on()
{
    if (!is_admin() && !is_login_page())
    {

        //flag false redirecting user to live site
        wp_redirect('https://example.com/location-new');
        exit; 

    }

}
add_action('init','check_user_on');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue before 15 days ago when I type  https://example.com then redirect to
https://example.com/?xtfw_notice=6f0a7ee281
here: **"?xtfw_notice=6f0a7ee281"**
this is a random tax.
but I have debugged my site,
resolved the issue after disable or remove plugin like: **XT WooCommerce Floating Cart**  and after that my site working fine.
So I have suggested please  check the plugin.
thanks.